# If it doesn't rain, we could

Tags: grammaticality

If it doesn't rain, we could go outside.

Is this correct?

(I am sitting on a couch looking out the window)

Comment: You might find it clearer to form the sentence as “We could go outside if it doesn’t rain.”

Answer (score 1):

In a word, yes.

Not knowing what you are exactly confused about, I will cover your question in different ways.

> Firstly, the dependent clause is just a conditional statement.

> Secondly, the essential clause says that you *"**could** go outside"* which implies the
> speaker's ***uncertainty or possibility*** of going outside even if it's very likely
> not to rain.

> Lastly, most grammars may have not mentioned this type of conditional sentence
> though it is not wrong or something native speakers wouldn't say.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's fine.

As well as your suggestion, there is a variety of clauses that might follow the conditional clause: **If it doesn't rain.**

> ....we ought to go outside.
> ....we might go outside.
> ....we should go outside.

and many other possibilities: We might consider going outside.

Each one is a slightly different way of saying much the same thing.
All are correct and idiomatic.
Which one you prefer simply depends on what you want to say.

Comment: Thanks. But "we would go out" can't be used is , at this point, purely absurd and error in the language.